# Looking for a word to describe the nature at higher places

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am looking for a word to describe nature at higher places, say, 2000 meters and above.

e.g. "I love ____ (mountains)" does not include water bodies, waterfalls, lakes, trees/shrubs/tundra, climate etc.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132721/discussion-on-question-by-shy-snail-looking-for-a-word-to-describe-the-nature-at).

Comment: I interpreted this to mean 'I'm looking for an expression that does not exclude water bodies, waterfalls, lakes etc, as I feel _mountains_ does, at least to some extent.' If you desire a word that actually connotes / denotes waterfalls, lakes, higher pastures, upland streams, upland forest etc, please advise.

Answer (score 15):

How about **alpine**?

> of, pertaining to, on, or part of any lofty mountain.

*very high; elevated.*

> growing on mountains above the limit of tree growth:

*alpine plants*

[Dictionary.com]

Additionally, this word is reminiscent of *The Alps* which should suit OP's purpose even better.

Comment: There are alpine lakes though, so that doesn't fit OP's requirement.

Comment: @pacoverflow I think the OP is looking for a term that encompasses all the nature on the mountains, not just the geography.

Comment: Might people confuse this word for "pertaining to the Alps", which would mean it's not necessarily the best word to use since listeners (especially, due to the lack of cues of capitalisation in spoken English) might think the speaker ONLY likes nature in The Alps, rather than nature in mountains generally?

Comment: You also get mountain lakes, high-altitude lakes, upland lakes, etc, so saying it's wrong because alpine lakes exist would seem to exclude almost any conceivable answer.

Comment: -1: This does not answer the question. The OP soecifically asked for a word that also connotated 'waterfall' or 'lakes'.

Comment: "Alpine botany" is a standard phrase for the plants of such high-altitude areas even outside the Alps, see [here](https://royalbcmuseum.bc.ca/collections/research-portal/research-project-profiles/alpine-botany-british-columbia) or the journal of the same name. Although the OP seems to want a noun.

Answer (score 8):

The adjective **montane** is used for such flora and fauna (and regions). Collins gives a very broad definition:

> *montane* [adjective]
>
> of or inhabiting mountainous regions

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/montane)]

While Merriam-Webster is more stipulative:

> *montane*
>
> - 1: of, relating to, growing in, or being the biogeographic zone of relatively moist cool upland slopes below timberline dominated by
>   large coniferous trees
> - 2: of, relating to, or made up of montane plants or animals
>
> Recent Examples on the Web
>
> - *This means that parts of the vast montane forest that once stretched across much of central Africa now has permanent protection
>   and is open to visitors.* — Judy Koutsky, Forbes, 4 Oct. 2021
> - *Spring is a lovely time to explore the foothill and montane landscapes of Salt Lake City, where sunflowers, gum weeds, and
>   bluebells are having their moment in the sun.* — Wendy Altschuler,
>   Forbes, 1 June 2021

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/montane)]

The 'sub-alpine' and 'alpine' zones are contrasted with the stipulative definition.

Comment: Where I live it goes like this: Plains = below 6k′ (treeless grasslands).
Foothills = 6-8k′ (shrubs, some trees).
Montane = 8–10k′ (trees with lush understory).
Subalpine = 10–12k′ (trees with sparse understory).
Alpine = 12-14k′ (treeless tundra above timberline) .

Comment: -1: This does not answer the question. The OP specifically asked for a word that also connotated 'waterfalls' and/or 'lakes'.

Comment: I interpreted this, Mozibur Ullah, to mean 'I'm looking for an expression that does not exclude water bodies, waterfalls, lakes etc, as I feel _mountains_ does (at least to some extent).' We should both have clarified. Note also that 'etc' may include other than water features, the clue here being in the title question. I'd say this makes your reading unjustified.

Answer (score 3):

> *I love highland lakes.*
>
> *I love highland waterfalls.*
>
> *I love highland trees.*
>
> *I love highland flora and fauna.*
>
> *I love highland clouds.*

> **highland**, *n.* and *adj.*
>
> **A. n.** **1. a.** Land which is naturally elevated in comparison to the surrounding area; high ground; the mountainous or elevated part of
> a country. Also: an area of such land, esp. a high headland or cliff.
>
> **B.** *adj.* **2.** *gen.* Of, relating to, or characteristic of a highland or highlands.
> <sub>[selected samples]</sub>
>  <sub>1853   E. K. KANE *U.S.
> Grinnell Exped.* (1856) xxiv. 199    Merely the highland clouds
> over the mountains.</sub>
> <sub>1951   *N.Y. Times*
> 15 Apr. xx. 19/1    The Blue Ridge mountains, from whose heights
> the flatlander can..understand the lure of highland life.</sub>
> <sub>2010   D. A. ROTHERY *Planets: Very Short Introd.* ii. 57   
> Some Mars scientists see evidence for glaciers, especially at the
> eroded edges of highland plateaus.</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but I guess the downvote was because *highlands* usually refers to much lower elevations than the question asks for — hills/plateaus rather than mountains proper.  The prototypical example is the Scottish highlands (mostly around 400–800m, highest point c.1400m), or see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highland_(disambiguation)) for more examples.

Comment: @PLL: *Highlands* (noun, plural, capital *h*) is different than *highland* (adjective), whose definition and examples I gave. The Blue Ridge mountains are over 2000m, and those highland clouds *are* over the "mountains."

Comment: @tchrist: I'm saying that the question is ill-formed as hence my answer is an an answer. To describe the Himalayans as alpine just comes across wromg because the word derives from the alps and montane is obscure and hardly ever used. Writers should be thinking expansively and not narrowly.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Just because you as a flatlander don't know these words means nothing at all, since [these words are common as mud here](https://www.google.com/search?q=colorado+plains+foothills+montane+subalpine+alpine&source=lmns&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZk_LTqIr1AhUC5awKHd4nCAYQ_AUoAHoECAEQAA).  You have fallen for the etymological fallacy: Alpine simply means above timberline in the treeless tundra, Subalpine is below that. Montane comes next. These are the standard terms for such things.

Comment: I mean the Blue Ridge Mountains aren’t all that high. The Rockies feel very different from any of the east coast ranges.

Answer (score 1):

I love *high altitudes*.  I thrive in a *thin atmosphere*.

(In case it's not obvious -- "thin atmosphere" refers to a place where the air pressure is low and the air molecules are more spread out.)

There are examples of the latter in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/thin-atmosphere), for example "It swiftly evaporated into the thin atmosphere."

Answer (score 0):

*At altitude* isn't a single word as you requested, but **nature at altitude** is sometimes used:

**at altitude** (idiom)

> At a high altitude, where the air is thin [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20altitude)

---

> Bernard Schouwey, nature photographer for twenty years, invites us to
> a little meander through all that **nature at altitude** has to offer
> in his current exhibition at the Espace Culturel in Vouvry. Looking at
> around 60 large size pictures leads us to dive into landscape, wild
> animals, flowers of Swiss, Italian, French Alps as well as Carpathian
> mountains. ["The Mountain Wild Life Seen by Bernard Shouwey" at
> livinginvaud](https://livinginvaud.wordpress.com/2018/09/24/the-mountain-wild-life-seen-by-bernard-shouwey/)

> Slushy science in action, compiling records over the years, that may
> reveal how the climate crisis is affecting **nature at altitude**.
> [Murdo McLeod; "Shrews and snow buntings – a post lockdown-easing
> diary", *The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2021/may/31/shrews-and-snow-buntings-a-post-lockdown-easing-diary)

> But this is precisely the art of **Nature at altitude.** [W. Aitken;
> "Serbjeet Singh: Artist and Alchemist", himalayanclub.org](https://www.himalayanclub.org/hj/65/2/serbjeet-singh-artist-and-alchemist/)

> Pretty mountain flower, this painting is a picture of **nature at
> altitude**. [The Pyrenean fritillary, scenolia.com](https://www.scenolia.com/en/2070-pyrenean-fritillary-canvas-print.html)